# error trapping without without a code behind page

Tags: gridview, error-handling

I have a gridview that uses an object data source. The method that loads the gridview is reading from a text file and creating a List which is bound to the gridview. If the data being read from the text file has a bad format data then the Person class throws an error which I want to display to the user on the page that contains the gridview. How do I trap that error when the page that has the gridview does not have a code behind page.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code or what programming languages you're using , it would be hard to help you , i suppose you have  to use a try catch on the methode of loading data and display the error message in the catch part

Comment: I am using C# building an ASP.NET page. The page has the gridview control but the data is provided by objectdatasource which has the methods in a different class not the page. I want to trap the error in the method in the class but display it on the page with the gridview